# How to Resolve a .so Dependency

Tags: centos, rpm, dependencies

I have a package (.rpm) on CentOS 6.5 that requires a .so file, which I also have on my machine. When I attempt to install the package I get an error stating unresolved dependencies regarding the .so file. I have tried placing the .so file in the same directory, in /lib/, in /usr/lib/, and setting the path of LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /usr/lib/, but regardless the package does not resolve the dependency, how can I make the .so available to the package I am installing?

Comment: Likely it's looking for another RPM which provides said `.so` file. Can you provide the full command and complete output, including error?

Comment: @Patrick the machine I'm using is isolated, but I am calling rpm -i [package name], and getting error: Failed Dependencies: [.so] is required by [package name]

Comment: Are you sure the target RPM's architecture is compatible with the `.so` file you have on your system?

Comment: @JosephR. it is possible that it is off, do you know how I would go about checking?

Comment: The `file` command can usually identify the architecture of your `.so` file. As for the RPM you're trying to install, the name should give you a clue about the architecture. `x86_64` and `amd64` usually refer to 64-bit RPMs and things like `i386`, `i686`,... usually refer to 32-bit RPMs.

Comment: @JosephR. The file command states my .so as '.., Intel 80386, ..' and the package is i686. Both are 32-bit, but I'm wondering that the difference would cause the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the output of `yum provides /full/path/to/file.so` ? As first comment suggested, the so might be installed outside rpm db (e.g. manually compiled or copied). Some non-official rpms are poorly packaged, and rely on dependencies in the developer's machine. It would help if you could provide the package name and source.

If the `.so` is present and you know it satisfies the requirements (version wise etc.) you can install the package with `rpm --nodeps`. However that is not a recommended practice.

UPDATE
As per @Centimane's comment, if the .so file is provided by an rpm, and that rpm is not installed on your system, it might be a good idea (depending on versions and making sure this would not break currently installed apps) to install the .so with the rpm found in the output of the `yum provides` command.

```
yum provides /full/path/to/file.so
yum install <package name found by previous command>
```

Or even directly

```
yum install /full/path/to/file.so
```

Comment: So revisiting this from long ago, I would recommend adding to your answer installing the package that `yum provides [file]` reports with `yum install [file]`.